# JSplitPane Resize Cursor

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I can't seem to change the resize cursor of JSplitPane by calling `setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));` Does anyone know how to get around this? I am using Nimbus UI.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setCursor` on a `JSplitPane` component will set the cursor *only* for left & right (or top & bottom) components.

To set the cursor for the divider component, you can use:

```
Component divider = ((BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI()).getDivider();
divider.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
```

Comment: Hmm, that approach works for right and left components, but not for the divider (at least on Nimbus LAF)

Comment: I can't say which method (on my phone), but you can access the divider by calling something like `getUI().getDivider()`, instead of "hacking" on `getComponent(2)`

Answer (score 0):

We can add code for mouse listener in addPropertyChangeListener() listener of JSplitPane and after loading of GUI we can fire this event to bind mouse listener to divider. Here is my code:

```
splitPanehor.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, (pce) -> {
        Component divider1 = ((JSplitPane) pce.getSource()).getComponent(2);
        divider1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                ExomDataGUI.f.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                ExomDataGUI.f.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
        });
    });
```

And we can fire this event after showing GUI in following way:

```
splitPanehor.firePropertyChange(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, 219, 220);
```